# Android LogCat is not working for emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am new in Android and java programming.
LogCat is woking fine for one of my emulator.
But same time it is not working for another emulator.

Can any body tell me any specific setting for it.

**EDIT**
@all DDMS Screenshot, I am using MAC operating system
[image]

@Shlublu
Its working fine with API Level 8 and Build In WVGA800
but not working with HVGA
sometime also not working with WVGA800

**Amit Battan**

Comment: Well, this question is not clear enough: which emulators are we talking about? (default, or vendor-specific? on which Android targets?) Are you connecting them thru Eclipse/debug or ddms?

Comment: check my answer. with eclipse screen shot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Look, top right side of your eclipse ide -> from java choose ddms -> then from ddms window bottom click on other -> devices -> then your emulator for which you want to show logcat 
Try this.

Comment: while this works 99% of the time - sometimes you also need to restart eclipse

Comment: Works fine on my MAC. However I do have to sometimes restart Eclipse when I have issues with Eclipse and emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Goto DDMS --> Select Device --> Select Name

It may be Emulator 5554, Emulator 5556

Comment: I have not found any setting in DDMS .. please check my edited question

Comment: I told you the method for Windows OS, I don,t know about MAC OS

Answer (score 0):

Go to DDMS and select the Emulator you want to dispaly hte logCat. And come back to the JAVA perspective. It will show the logs of selected emulator.

Comment: You need not yo go in prefrences(DDMS).

Comment: Windows-->open perspective-->DDMS-->>on the left corner there are shown all the emulators--> select one(5554 or 5556 or whatever the name is)--> go to Java perspective again & show the log cat.

Answer (score 0):

if you run `adb devices` you will get a list of devices attached to your Android Debug Bridge. You can run a command on a specific one by adding the -s switch, so this

```
adb -s devicename logcat
```

should give you what you need.

Anthony